# Curvature lines are coordinate curves if and only if Weingarten matrix is diagonal

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have to prove that the curvature lines are the coordinate curves of a surface S if and only if the matrix associated to the Weingarten endomorphism is diagonal.

The matrix is written in the canonical base of the tangent plane (r_u, r_v, where r is the parametrization of the surface S).

Can someone give me some hints or show me how to do it?
Thank you in advice

Comment: Start with the definition of lines of curvature. P.S. Don’t post your homework with zero effort.